# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio

I don't understand why I am getting this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near '12'.'

My code:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class produktm
    Dim Con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\MON\Documents\profitmon.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30")
    Public Sub populate()
        Con.Open()
        Dim sql = "select * from ProduktTable"
        Dim adapter As SqlDataAdapter
        adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(sql, Con)
        Dim builder As SqlCommandBuilder
        builder = New SqlCommandBuilder(adapter)
        Dim ds As DataSet
        ds = New DataSet
        adapter.Fill(ds)
        ProduktDataList.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)

        Con.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Con.Open()
            Dim query As String
            query = "Insert Into ProduktTable values(" & ProduktId.Text & ",'" & ProdEmri.Text & ",'" & ProdSasia.Text & ",'" & ProdQmimi.Text & ",'" & ProdPershkrimi.Text & ",'" & ProdKategori.SelectedItem.ToString() & "')"
            Dim cmd As SqlCommand
            cmd = New SqlCommand(query, Con)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("Produkti u shtua me sukses")
            Con.Close()

    End Sub

    Private Sub produktm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        populate()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Visual Studio is saying that this line is the problem

```
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: Please stop SHOUTING. Text in ALL CAPS is more difficult to read and understand, and SHOUTING won't get you help any faster. It's also rather impolite to be shouting at us when you're asking us for help. Thanks.

Comment: If you dynamically generate sql statements, the first part to debugging any errors related to their execution is to LOOK at the generated statement. And stop with the lazy and bad habits. Always specify the column list in an insert statement.

Comment: All the stuff about sql injections and stuff while valid is not really the best reason for using parameters.  Really as a developer, just makes executing sql statements a massive amount more simple, maintainable and just all around more pleasant rather than all the issues that come up around sting concatenations

Comment: It looks like your single quotes are matching up. Double check what values should have the single quotes around them. I agree with @SMor, to generate your sql statements to see what you are passing to SQL.

Answer (score 0):

you're missing some apostrohpes:

```
query = "Insert Into ProduktTable values(" & ProduktId.Text & ",'" & ProdEmri.Text & ",'" & ProdSasia.Text & ",'" & ProdQmimi.Text & ",'" & ProdPershkrimi.Text & ",'" & ProdKategori.SelectedItem.ToString() & "')"
```

should be

```
query = "Insert Into ProduktTable values('" & ProduktId.Text & "','" & ProdEmri.Text & ",'" & ProdSasia.Text & "','" & ProdQmimi.Text & "','" & ProdPershkrimi.Text & "','" & ProdKategori.SelectedItem.ToString() & "')"
```

to help, add this line:

```
Debug.WriteLine(query)
```

and then copy/paste the output into SSMS and test

There are better ways to do this though that won't open you up to sql injection, but this should fix the current issue.

Comment: Both the question and your answer are subject to SQL Injection vulnerabilities. Obligatory [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) reference.

Comment: You should include information specifically about those *better ways* and point out why the concatenation of SQL is a very bad idea. This is a site intended to educate and share knowledge.

Comment: sorry, i had 5 minutes and thought I'd help out a beginner as we all need to start somewhere.

Comment: mm it didnt wok, i edited my question, please take a look if u got time

Comment: Make sure that you're using standard double (") and single (') quote characters and *not* the ones you get in, say, Outlook email. Also, break on the assignment and look at the resultant string. You can even copy that string and try directly executing it in SSMS. These strings can be tricky when constructed in code, especially where the variables can contains quote marks themselves. Also, make sure that only string types are enclosed in single quotes; numeric types should not be. You need to get to grips with the basic SQL syntax before trying to construct this stuff in code, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

[Set a breakpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/quickstart-debug-with-managed?view=vs-2019) to the 'query' line and check the 'query' string.

[image]

Try the following code:

```
query = "Insert Into ProduktTable values('" & ProduktId.Text & "','" & ProdEmri.Text & "','" & ProdSasia.Text & "','" & ProdQmimi.Text & "','" & ProdPershkrimi.Text & "','" & ProdKategori.SelectedItem.ToString() & "')"
```

Answer (score 0):

Sub populate()

Do not declare connection at the Class level. They need to be closed and disposed with `Using...End Using` blocks. Keep you connections in the method where they are used.  To save typing create a string variable containing the Connection String at the class level. Don't open the connection until directly before it is use, before the `.Execute...`. `DataAdapter.Fill` and `DataAdapter.Update` will open and closed the connection if it finds the connection closed. You don't need `DataSet`, `CommandBuilder` or `DataAdapter`. Your `DataAdapter` falls out of scope at the `End Sub`. Do no mix your database code with your user interface code.

```
Private Sub produktm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim dt = populate()
    ProduktDataList.DataSource = dt
End Sub

Public Function populate() As DatTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using Con As New SqlConnection(ConStr),
            cmd As New SqlCommand("select * from ProduktTable", Con)
        Con.Open()
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
    End Using
    Return dt
End Function
```

Button1_Click and InsertNewProductID

You will do any validation of the user input in the button click before calling `InsertNewProduct`. Always list the database field names  as part of your Insert.

**Always use parameters.**

I had to guess at the column names I used in the Insert statement. I also had to guess at the datatype and size of the fields for the `Parameters.Add`. Please check you database for the correct values.

I am concerned that the `ProduktId` field is an auto-number, identity field. If this is true, it should not be included in the field list in the Insert. There should be no parameter created for it and no value should be passed. The database provides the value.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim RecordsEntered = InsertNewProduct(CInt(ProduktId.Text), ProdEmri.Text, ProdSasia.Text, ProdQmimi.Text, ProdPershkrimi.Text, ProdKategori.SelectedItem.ToString())
    If RecordsEntered = 1 Then
        MsgBox("Produkti u shtua me sukses")
    End If
End Sub

Private Function InsertNewProduct(Id As Integer, Emri As String, Sasia As String, Qmimi As String, Persh As String, Kategori As String) As Integer
    Dim RetVal As Integer
    Dim sql = "Insert Into ProduktTable (
                ProduktId,
                ProdEmri,
                ProdSasia,
                ProdQmimi,
                ProdPershkrimi,
                ProdKategori)
                Values
                (@ID, @Emri,@Sasia, @Qmimi, @Persh, @Kategori);"
    Using Con As New SqlConnection(ConStr),
            cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, Con)
        With cmd.Parameters
            .Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Id
            .Add("@Emri", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = Emri
            .Add("@Sasia", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = Sasia
            .Add("@Qmimi", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = Qmimi
            .Add("@Persh", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = Persh
            .Add("@Kategori", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = Kategori
        End With
        Con.Open()
        RetVal = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
    Return RetVal
End Function
```

This may seem like a great deal of changes but using parameters and handling connections and commands correctly are important to the overall success of you application.

Please check my spelling of field and table names. I can barely spell my own language.  :-)